# Using Powershell, add multiple items in Clipboard (windows 10), separately, each of them in each clipboard

Tags: windows, powershell, clipboard

Using Powershell, add multiple items in Clipboard (windows 10, keystroke Windows + V), separately, each of them in each clipboard

For ex, the below code will only store last value in clipboard, I need 1 to 5 to be store in clipboard, separately (so when I paste I can paste them 1 by 1):

$values = @(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)

foreach ($value in $values) {
Set-Clipboard -Value $value
}

I need 1 to 5 to be store in clipboard, separately (so when I paste I can paste them 1 by 1)

Comment: Are you referring to Win+V (clipboard history) ?

Comment: See my linked answer. You need to add a sleep timer for each iteration (`Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 250`)